# Maven shading "Project main artifact doesnt exist"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, mule, maven-shade-plugin

I googled this issue and i ran into [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494743/m2e-shade-eclipse-project-main-artifact-does-not-exist), however i'm already doing everything mentioned there, and its still giving me the error.

Here's the full error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.1.1:shade (default) on project b1_sync_master: Failed to create shaded artifact, project main artifact does not exist.
```

And Here's the full POM file (just in case i dont miss anything that might be relevant)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>b1_sync_master</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <name>Mule b1_sync_master Application</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <mule.version>3.9.0</mule.version>
        <mule.tools.version>1.7</mule.tools.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.kordamp.shade</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-ext-transformers</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                    </transformers>
                    <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
                    <artifactSet>
                        <includes>
                            <include>com.sap.jdbc:sap-jdbc</include>
                        </includes>
                    </artifactSet>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.sap.db.annotations</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>com.shadeSync.sap.db.annotations</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.sap.db.jdbc</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>com.shadeSync.sap.db.jdbc</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.sap.db.jdbc.converters</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>com.shadeSync.sap.db.jdbc.converters</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>com.shadeSync.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.sap.db.jdbc.packet</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>com.shadeSync.sap.db.jdbc.packet</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.sap.db.jdbc.trace</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>com.shadeSync.sap.db.jdbc.trace</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.sap.db.jdbcext</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>com.shadeSync.sap.db.jdbcext</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.sap.db.jdbc.wrapper</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>com.shadeSync.sap.db.jdbc.wrapper</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.sap.db.util</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>com.shadeSync.sap.db.util</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.sap.db.util.security</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>com.shadeSync.sap.db.util.security</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>net.jpountz.lz4</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>net.shadeSync.jpountz.lz4</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>net.jpountz.util</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>net.shadeSync.jpountz.util</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>org.java_websocket</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>org.shadeSync.java_websocket</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>org.java_websocket.client</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>org.shadeSync.java_websocket.client</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>org.java_websocket.drafts</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>org.shadeSync.java_websocket.drafts</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>org.java_websocket.exceptions</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>org.shadeSync.java_websocket.exceptions</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>org.java_websocket.extensions</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>org.shadeSync.java_websocket.extensions</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>org.java_websocket.framing</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>org.shadeSync.java_websocket.framing</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>org.java_websocket.handshake</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>org.shadeSync.java_websocket.handshake</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>org.java_websocket.util</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>org.shadeSync.java_websocket.util</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>mappings/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- SAP HANA JDBC DRIVER -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>sap-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JODA TIME -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Transports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-schedulers</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-email</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-db</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-release</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I'm running mvn package, but it still doenst work. Here's the output from `mvn package -e`:

```
C:\workspace\b1_sync_master>mvn package -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------< com.mycompany:b1_sync_master >--------------------
[INFO] Building Mule b1_sync_master Application 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ mule ]--------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- mule-app-maven-plugin:1.7:attach-test-resources (default-attach-test-
resources) @ b1_sync_master ---
[INFO] attaching test resource C:\workspace\b1_sync_master\src\main\app
[INFO]
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:add-resource (add-resource) @ b1_sync_m
aster ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ b1_sync_
master ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\workspace\b1_sync_master\mappings
[INFO]
[INFO] --- mule-app-maven-plugin:1.7:filter-resources (default-filter-resources)
 @ b1_sync_master ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- mule-app-maven-plugin:1.7:process-resources (default-process-resource
s) @ b1_sync_master ---
[INFO] attachMuleSources default value is false, skipping process-resources goal
...
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ b1_sync_maste
r ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 18 source files to C:\workspace\b1_sync_master\target\classes
[INFO] /C:/workspace/b1_sync_master/src/main/java/sapb1masterpoll/JSONCleaner.ja
va: C:\workspace\b1_sync_master\src\main\java\sapb1masterpoll\JSONCleaner.java u
ses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /C:/workspace/b1_sync_master/src/main/java/sapb1masterpoll/JSONCleaner.ja
va: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @
b1_sync_master ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ b1_sy
nc_master ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test (default-test) @ b1_sync_master -
--
[INFO]
[INFO] --- mule-app-maven-plugin:1.7:mule (default-mule) @ b1_sync_master ---
[INFO] Copying classes directly
[INFO] Copying api directly
[INFO] Adding <com.sap.jdbc:sap-jdbc:jar:1.0> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.6> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.6> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.1> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.6> as a li
b
[INFO] Adding <org.apache.activemq:activemq-all:jar:5.15.7> as a lib
[INFO] C:\workspace\b1_sync_master\mappings does not exist, skipping
[INFO] C:\workspace\b1_sync_master\target\META-INF does not exist, skipping
[INFO] Building zip: C:\workspace\b1_sync_master\target\b1_sync_master-1.0.0-SNA
PSHOT.zip
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:3.1.1:shade (default) @ b1_sync_master ---
[ERROR] The project main artifact does not exist. This could have the following
[ERROR] reasons:
[ERROR] - You have invoked the goal directly from the command line. This is not
[ERROR]   supported. Please add the goal to the default lifecycle via an
[ERROR]   <execution> element in your POM and use "mvn package" to have it run.
[ERROR] - You have bound the goal to a lifecycle phase before "package". Please
[ERROR]   remove this binding from your POM such that the goal will be run in
[ERROR]   the proper phase.
[ERROR] - You removed the configuration of the maven-jar-plugin that produces th
e main artifact.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.190 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-01T10:54:48-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.1.1
:shade (default) on project b1_sync_master: Failed to create shaded artifact, pr
oject main artifact does not exist. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.1.1:shade (default) on project b1_s
ync_master: Failed to create shaded artifact, project main artifact does not exi
st.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav
a:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessor
Impl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche
r.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2
29)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc
her.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356
)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to create shad
ed artifact, project main artifact does not exist.
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.execute (ShadeMojo.java:400
)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBui
ldPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav
a:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessor
Impl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche
r.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2
29)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc
her.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356
)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you are trying to use the shade plugin in a Mule project instead of a Java project. Probably it can not find the main artifact due to that. An alternative could be to create a Java jar project, do the shade inside it and use the generated jar as a dependency in the Mule project.