# maven install does not copy all launch4j created executables

Tags: maven, launch4j

When using a POM like the one from the following answer (
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6194218/2764459) maven install only copies executables named ${project.artifactId}.exe to the repo.

So if I have two executions to create separate windows executables (CLI and GUI)

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>l4j-cli</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>launch4j</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <headerType>console</headerType>
            <outfile>target/${project.artifactId}-cli.exe</outfile>
    ...
</execution>
<execution>
    <id>l4j-gui</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>launch4j</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <headerType>gui</headerType>
        <outfile>target/${project.artifactId}-gui.exe</outfile>
    ...
</execution>
</executions>
```

There will be NO executable in the repository!

Is there something I can configure for the install-plugin?

Answer (score 0):

> Alternatively, You can omit the 'jar' tag on launch4j-plugin and remove the extra configs of the shade-plugin, but be aware that this will replace the main jar of the flow (without embedded dependencies) by the shaded jar (with embedded dependencies), and this one will be installed on your local repo, or used in the reactor if needed.

As I tried to explain there, the setup I provided on https://stackoverflow.com/a/6194218/2764459 create the executable artifact as a side artifact, no the main one. This may explain why it is not copied to the repo. Try to remove  true and shaded and the "-shaded" suffix from the  tag and see if it works.