# Izpack installer can't run without java

Tags: java, windows, installation, exe, izpack

I've created a java application , and its installer with izpack , I can setup my application with out any problems when the machine has JRE , but when there is no JRE installed on the machine I get an error indicating that "Windows cannot find javaw. Make sure you typed name correcly and try again." Is there a way that I can pop up some friendly panel to user to tell him to install jre , or is there a way to bundle a jre inside the exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I surfed the internet till I came across an article talking about Izpack native launcher [(Building Native Windows Installers with IzPack Native Launcher)](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/izpack/); which provides three options which I really needed , and these options are :

1. manually specify a JRE location
2. download one from the Internet
3. install one that is provided by the packager (if available).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven to build your installer the launch4j-maven-plugin will help you with this.

You find the details for using it in another question already answered on stackoverflow here: [Trying to integrate Launch4j in a Maven project using Alakai plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060560/trying-to-integrate-launch4j-in-a-maven-project-using-alakai-plugin)